# XML literals with namespace

Tags: xml, rdf

RDF has a way of assigning literal values to a namespace:

`<owl:cardinality rdf:datatype="&xsd;nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:cardinality>`

Notice the `&xsd;` prefix which corresponds to the `xsd` namespace declaration `xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"`.

Is this an RDF specific syntax or is it standard XML?

Comment: Note that this works in RDF/XML, but not necessarily in other [serialization formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework#Serialization_formats) of RDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are [XML entity references](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-references) - it's part of the XML standard, not part of RDF per se.